# Have an indentation for a line after \\ (no, I can't change it into a blank line)

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, parindent

Imagine that I want to use `\\` to end a line and start a new one (can't just insert a blank line due to a macro argument and also can't change it into `\par`).

That is not purely imaginative, it is actually the case I am in.

My question is: how can I indent every line after `\\`?

`\parindent` does the job for `\par`, now doesn't it?

Is it possible for `\\` as well?

Comment: it is not that it is not a_advisable_ to end a paragraph with `\\ ` it simply does not work, `\\ ` does not end a paragraph, it's like asking to end the paragraph with `\mbox{}` Also you should almost never need `\par` in a document as a blank line ends a paragraph. If you are in a macro argument that doesn't allow `\par` use `\endgraf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That explains a lot, and `\endgraf` solved the problem. Let me rephrase the question a bit to make it a bit more sensible again then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you process

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\zzz[1]{#1}%does not allow paragraphs

\begin{document}

\zzz{aaa\endgraf bbb} % two paragraphs

\zzz{aaa

bbb}
\end{document}
```

then you get the error below as `\zzz` does not allow normal paragraph breaks. If you replace the blank line (`\par`) by `\endgraf` as in the first example then it works.

`\\` in normal text does not end a paragraph so will never trigger `\parskip` space or paragraph indentation.

```
{aaa 
! Paragraph ended before \zzz was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10 

?
```